# jQuery POST, Error 405 Method not allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I am trying to host an ASP.NET MVC4 web application with IIS 7.5. When debugging the app everything works fine (I'm assuming this is because of Windows Authentication). 
However, when I publish the app and browse to it I get a 405 Method not allowed error:

```
POST http://localhost/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
send 
i.extend.ajax 
i.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
```

From what I've been reading this is either a problem with the Handler Mappings in IIS or some configuration is needed in the web.config. Either way, I have not found the correct solution.
Could anyone tell me what my web.config should include to all POSTS? And/or how to set up the correct Handler mapping in IIS, as I am new to web development and find the number of options a bit overwhelming.

The piece of javascript that throws the error is the following:

```
$.post("/", { latitude: locLat, longitude: locLon, username: $('#onlineUsers').attr('itemid') });
```

Comment: if you examine the fire bug or chrome dev tools, the url is correct to which the request is being made?

Comment: The request is in the Index method of the Home controller. I have tried POST with both '/' and 'Home/Index' as URLs and both give the same error, but I believe them to be correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A 405 is thrown by IIS when an HTTP verb(GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD,etc.) is requested and is not supported/disallowed by the designated handler.

You'll need to open the IIS manager -> Default Web Site -> Handler Mappings (Or the handler mappings specific to your web-application)

[image]

In here you'll need to play with the handler mappings as one of them is not allowing "POST" verbs.

As you are not posting to any specific page (.aspx, .ashx, etc.), it will be difficult to identify the exact handler that is causing you issues.

Handlers of interest may be:

- ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit /64bit
- StaticFile

Once you identify the handler your request is being routed to, double click it to open the dialogue.

[image]

From there click "Request Restrictions" then "Verbs"

Make sure the appropriate verb is present in the text area.

[image]

As I mentioned before, I'm not sure which handler is handling your request as you are not posting to any particular page (you may have URL re-writing in place that is routing your request appropriately).

---

If the above fails, you may need to check if WebDAV Publishing is installed and remove it (restart required).

[image: WebDAV]

Comment: The Static file handler was the problem. Thanks for the help, great answer!

Comment: but after implementing this its works for me but asp:link button stop to work . Do you know why this issues comes ?

Comment: If i use only GET, POST jquery ajax works but asp:link button stop working , and if i use all as shown in your image then jquer.post throw 405 error .

Comment: I have a feeling you may need to set these properties on a different handler. I'm not sure which handler an asp:link button uses (.aspx handler?) or which handler is managing your jQuery post. That said, adding verbs shouldn't increase security on a handler so I'm not sure why you would get a 405 by adding new verbs.

Comment: WEBDav module was the problem in my case. Thanks Man

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should modify your post'URl format like this:

```
$.post('@Url.Content("~/Attach/UpdateAttach")'
```

Answer (score 0):

some users here are having shared hosting and not dedicated servers, so they might not be able to get access to the IIS control panel..

this is my case and here is what I found..

I have my web application on the root directory created through Godaddy control panel.. and the POST request is acknowledged ..

then I used the FileZilla to create a testing folder for my jquery ..( notice i used FileZilla , so the web application and hence the IIS of GoDaddy is not aware that I wanted this folder to be part of my we application )

then whenever I test this jQuery on this testing folder.. I get that error [405 Method not allowed]..

the solution was extremely simple :

I moved my testing page out of that testing folder created by FileZilla and located it inside a folder that was created through Godaddy control panel ( in this case the IIS will be aware that this page is part of my web application :) )

Hope that will help those on Shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

This is rather an old issue but still happens. If WebDav does not fix it, try adding Asp.net features to Windows from "Turn Windows features on or off".

[image]