# 405 error not allowed whereas I have javascript error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a really strange problem and I want to know how it's possible...

I develop an app with ASP on the server side and some JS/Ajax on the client. And for several times already, when I have a JS error, the page change and I get a 405 error instead of seeing the error in the Chrome console...

For example, my current error is to try to access a property on a null object... After this code, I'm sending a request but I have placed a lot of alert() to trace the execution of my code and the Ajax request code isn't reached...

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258014/jquery-post-error-405-method-not-allowed - http://www.somacon.com/p126.php

Comment: *"I have placed a lot of alert() to trace the execution of my code"* - You need to learn how to debug JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: Without showing the code your guess is better than ours.

Comment: @Šime Vidas "You need to learn how to debug JavaScript in the browser. ". If you have any advice....
I think I know how to debug cause I use the Chrome console, but here the page is reload so the console too...

Comment: @46enforce Well, set a break point, and step through the code, until the error occurs (or the Ajax request, whichever comes first).

Comment: @Šime Vidas  How to set a breakpoint? I am very interested to do that! :)
Edit: found it! Why I have never fount it before??? I spent so much time trying to debug JS... :/

Comment: @46enforce Setting break points is a core part of debugging a programming language, isn't it?

Comment: Of course, I use it a lot in other languages and it was a big lack for me not to use it in JS...