# The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. c#

Tags: asp.net

So I am working in a project to send data from a C# application to ASP web application; the problem is when I want to send the data I get this error :**The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.**  Here is my C# code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            string url = "http://localhost:4241/HtmlPage2.html";
            data["Text1"] = "Anas";
            data["Text2"] = "Anas";
            var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
        }
    }
```

and here my ASP code (*it's just a HTML page for testing, the code is implemented in `HtmlPage2.html` and  when I submit the button it passes the data to `HtmlPage2.html`*)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="Post" action="HtmlPage2.html">
        <input id="Text1" type="text" name="Text1" />
        <input id="Text2" type="text" name="Text2" />
        <input id="Button1" type="submit" value="button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

NB:My IIS is already enabled :)
So if someone can help me I will be very appreciative :)

Comment: This thread seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258014/jquery-post-error-405-method-not-allowed. To paraphrase: Check your Handler Mappings in IIS.  For the *.html mapping, check the Request Restrictions and make sure that POST is either in the list of accepted verbs or that the All verbs option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

A HTML file is a static file on a filesystem-based webserver, there is no way for it to handle POST requests, only GET (unless you're using WebDAV, but that's another story).

Basically the `<form action="HtmlPage2.html">` fragment is incorrect. If it does work in your webbrowser then check the DOM of the page to see if the `action` attribute is being changed.

Comment: Ok thanks Dai, so have any idea how to do it, i have a c# application and ASP web application and i want to send a request from c# to Asp

Comment: By "C# application" I assume you mean a WinForms desktop application. Your code is fine (largely), but you need to understand how the website you're sending data to works. Do that, then come back and ask again.