# Bootstrap PHP contact form not submitting and giving 405 error

Tags: php, contact-form

I've been working on trying to get a simple contact form made with bootstrap working but PHP is a bit over my head and I can't seem to figure out why nothing is being submitted.  When I inspect the code I see a "405 Method Not Allowed" error is occurring somewhere, but I don't know how to track down.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the site and form in question: https://actsdisplay.med.fsu.edu/NewSite/contact.html

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST['interest'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['interest'])) > 0)) {
    $name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['interest']));
} else {$name = 'No interest selected';}
if ((isset($_POST['name'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['name'])) > 0)) {
    $name = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
} else {$name = 'No name entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['email'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) > 0)) {
    $email = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
} else {$email = 'No email entered';}
if ((isset($_POST['phone'])) && (strlen(trim($_POST['phone'])) > 0)) {
    $message = stripslashes(strip_tags($_POST['phone']));
} else {$message = 'No phone entered';}
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="550" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeff">
    <td>Interest</td>
    <td><?=$interest;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?=$name;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeff">
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?=$email;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeeeff">
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td><?=$phone;?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#eeffee">
    <td>Message</td>
    <td><?=$message;?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?
$body = ob_get_contents();

$to = 'mark.bauer@med.fsu.edu';
$email = 'email@example.com';
$fromaddress = "you@example.com";
$fromname = "Online Contact";

require("phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->From     = "mark.bauer@med.fsu.edu";
$mail->FromName = "Mark Bauer";
$mail->AddAddress("mark.bauer@med.fsu.edu","Med"); // Put your email

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  =  "Contact form submitted";
$mail->Body     =  $body;
$mail->AltBody  =  "This is the text-only body";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $recipient = 'mark.bauer@med.fsu.edu';
    $subject = 'Contact form failed';
    $content = $body;   
  mail($recipient, $subject, $content, "From: mail@yourdomain.com\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nX-Mailer: DT_formmail");
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: What method is being used? It looks like the form is using `POST` but this might be modified with javascript.

Comment: Yes, I believe it's using POST

Comment: You are getting that on process.php. So where is that at?

Comment: Replace the `action="/contact.html"` by `action=""`, to make the page re-execute itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery POST, Error 405 Method not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258014/jquery-post-error-405-method-not-allowed)

Answer (score 0):

> 405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form.
>
> All 405 errors can be traced to configuration of the Web server and security governing access to the content of the Web site, so should easily be explained by your ISP.

Comment: OK I'll look into that. Thanks