# ASP MVC: HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, http-status-code-405

I have ASP MVC 4 Visual Studio 2017 project running in my Windows 10 machine. When my page loads, it makes jquery ajax post call to load contents of the page. Now when i run the project, it is giving me **HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed** error page.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt0vK.png)

Here is what i did so far:

- Checked WebDAV and make sure it is not running.
- Made sure all the handlers has appropriate verbs. Actually i added 'GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE' in all **handlers** tag in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config file just to make sure i don't miss anyone.

Note: This site was working previously when i ran through my Visual Studio 2017. I configure project to use SSL and that is when i started running into this 405 error. I changed the project not to use SSL but still i am running into this 405 error.

Can you guys suggest how i can fix this issue?
Thanks

Razor Code:

```
<ul class="partialContents" data-url="@Url.Action("LoadUser", "BaseWeb")"></ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".partialContents").each(function (index, item){
    var url = $(item).data("url");
    if (url && url.length > 0) {
        $(item).load(url);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadUser()
{
    var httpClient = await GetHttpClient(); <--returns WebAPI running locally
    UserModel requestModel = new UserModel();
    requestModel.Email = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/user/", requestModel);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var userModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserModel>>(result);

    return PartialView("_LoadUser", userModel);
}
```

Comment: please can you show us your ajax.

Comment: @Harry, added snapshot of code.

Comment: have you looked here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258014/jquery-post-error-405-method-not-allowed

Comment: yupe, that looks good. As one of the thing i did was have all the verb in handlers in applicationhost.config file to have 'GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE' so it looks good. Also i don't have WebDAV installed.

Comment: When are you getting the 405 response (or the screenshot you shared)?  as the response to your ajax call ? How did you get the screenshot ?

Comment: Okay. I just ran your code in iis express and it worked fine... i just didnt use an async action result and populated a static partial view into the partialContents class. If you remove all of the code on the page does it still throw the same error? Are you able to debug it at all? By the way i dont think .load will not throw this error screen. Jquery added error handling to .load()

Comment: @Harry it is running as Local IIS, not in IIS Express. #Shyju, the error appears on index page i.e. Home/Index.cshtml since _Layout.cshtml has the code that loads partial view.

Comment: I think the 405 error is the reponse to the initial request for your page and your javascript etc is not even running.

Comment: To start with, you should not be accessing the view directly. You should request the index action method which returns the view.Try (`/Home/index`).

Comment: The other problem could be that you are making HTTPS request to the API which only supprts http.

Comment: @Harry when you say initial request which one wud that be..since javascript is in _Layout.cshtml..it shud be running at the same time. I added debugged on both HomeController Index Actionmethod and ActionMethod that jquery ajax calls, it doesn't even get hit the breakpoint.

Comment: @Shyju adding /Home/index didn't work.

Comment: Razor is is a c# templating which runs on the server. your layout and views are all build on the server and no javascript runs at all. The javascript runs when you return a page to the clients browser.

Comment: What url are you exactly trying ? Do you have an index action method in homecontroller which returns some valid response ?

Comment: @Harry Oh ok. In that case, server is my local IIS and right now 'StaticFile' handler does allow all HttpVerbs, but still it is giving my that 405 error. #Shyju, the index just loads the page (no logic here), pretty much (return View() code), however the _Layout.cshtml page makes .load call to webapi to load user information.

Comment: please put a break point in your global asax application start and step through.

Have you tried to add attribute routing to any of your controller actions?

Comment: @harry, added breakpoint in global.asax.cs but it didn't hit breakpoint either.

Comment: you have misconfigured iis. Whatever you are trying to point at in IIS is not hitting your application at all.
how are you attaching to the process?

Comment: @harry, you might be right about misconfiguring iis part. not sure how to do undo it now :(

Comment: are you pressing f5/debug in visual studio in order to attach to the process? have you edited your projects properties to point to the correct local iis link or what?

Comment: as far as pointing to right iis link, i think it is good, i have double checked my local webapi. also my mvc project is running in local iis and created virtual directory from visual studio. i am debugging hitting F5.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I am having this exact same problem.  Application worked fine.  as soon as I turned on SSL I started getting this 405.0 error.  I am trying to do a post but it says post is not supported.  Looked at the modules and it has * which I thought meant supports all verbs.