# Having trouple uploading to virtual directory via http in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wcf, http, stream, response

Trying to upload an image to HTTP virtual directory and I keep getting this exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

```
Dim mFileStream As New FileStream("/Image Location/", FileMode.Open)
Dim mRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("/URL/")
mRequest.Headers.Set("filename", "new name")
mRequest.Proxy = New WebProxy("/URL/", True)
mRequest.Method = "POST"
mRequest.ContentLength = mFileStream.Length
Dim mCredentials As New NetworkCredential
mCredentials.Password = "/pass/"
mCredentials.UserName = "/Login Name/"
mRequest.Credentials = mCredentials
Dim mData(mFileStream.Length - 1) As Byte
mFileStream.Read(mData, 0, mFileStream.Length)
mFileStream.Close()
Using dataStream As Stream = mRequest.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(mData, 0, mData.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
End Using

Dim mResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(mRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
mResponse.Close()
```

Upon further investigation, I have found the reason for the WebException is:

> ProtocolError The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you Andrew , this block is inside a try catch statement  and it only gives me this message

Comment: @AndrewMorton the same Error its just an HTTP thing i guess that's why there is not much of a message on the stack trace

Comment: Microsoft have written about this exact thing: [Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.Net.WebException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48ww3ee9.aspx).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you for the Great advice , i now get 
**ProtocolError
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.**
this means i am not allowed to use post on this server while i can from other devices

Comment: @AndrewMorton i have searched , and nothing solved my problem , yes i am in control of the server , its an IIS virtual directory

Comment: How about [jQuery POST, Error 405 Method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13259689/1115360)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple despite everything i tried
you have to specify the file name in the url

```
Dim mRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("/URL/")
```

to

```
Dim mRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("/URL/" & FileName & FileExtention)
```

ex:

> Dim mRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://1.1.1.1/niveimage.png")