# Angular 405 method not allowed error when making HTTP POST request from PingID/SSO authentication

Tags: angular, iis

I have developed an Angular app and deployed it on the IIS web server. The website is enabled with PingID/SSO authentication (OpenTokenHttpModule). When we access the Angular app from the browser, it will redirect to PingId authentication. Once the authentication is complete, it will redirect to the app. The request is coming as an HTTP POST to the Angular app. I am getting an error status of: 405 Method Not Allowed.

This issue is not happening when I remove the OpenTokenHttpModule (Ping ID) for the Angular website.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3n22.png)

Any help from the expert would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I removed WebDAVModule and WebDAV by adding below code in web.config file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I referrred below article but no use.

https://tecadmin.net/aspnet-core-iis-405-method-not-allowed/

[jQuery POST, Error 405 Method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258014/jquery-post-error-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: could you try adding this code in your config file: `<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added it in web.config, but still, it's not working.

Comment: could you share error from the console